# keras, scikit-learn, python, binary classification confusion matrix (I may have a bug)

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

Here is the code for viewing in github with example output also visible as far as I can see(works for me) It's jupyter notebook on github.
https://github.com/late347/cognitive-systems-health-applications/blob/master/NeuralNetworks_case1_v1.ipynb

I'm making a neural network for binary classification with python and keras and scikit-learn

My neural network seemed to compile and train and validate rather nicely.

The problem is at the end of my code, where there is the confusion matrix printouts... those don't look reasonable results for the confusion matrix
Probably the issue is somewhere near here

```
# Print total accuracy and confusion matrix
val_predicts = model.predict(df_norm)
y_pred = argmax(val_predicts, axis = 1)
cm = confusion_matrix(groundTruth, y_pred)
print(val_predicts)
print(y_pred)
print(cm)
```

With the graph, and if you choose verbose=1 in the validation phase, you can see that the accuracy tends to about 80% with some overfitting visible from the graph.

But in the y-pred printouts, I have all the values as zeroes...

I'm not sure what causes this... how can the y-pred be all zeroes if the accuracy is about 80%.

I remembered to use sigmoid on the output layer also, but I have a nagging feeling that you still have to round those results that you get from sigmoid.
(i.e. if your sigmoid results are above or equal to 0.5 => convert to 1.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y_pred = argmax(val_predicts, axis = 1)` this causes your prediction to output all zeros since you have only one one element array and the maximum is obviously the item at zero-th index. Instead you should do something like the following

```
y_pred = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in val_predicts]
```

Comment: what I did was that I just replaced that line with val_predicts = model.predict(df_norm)


y_pred = 1*(val_predicts >= 0.5)

Comment: it works because of the numpy style computation I think, it just rounds-up or rounds-down those values inside val_predicts and assigns them into y_pred